# Where are the implicit unit matrices in Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider the Hamiltonian term:

$$H=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left[S_{x}^{4}+S_{y}^{4}+S_{z}^{4}-\frac{1}{5} S(S+1)\left(3 S^{2}+3 S-1\right)\right]$$
where $S_x,\ S_y,\ S_z$ are spin operators.
I know there are implicit unit matrices in an expression like this, but where exactly does it, or they,  belong in this expression?

Comment: This is a Hamiltonian operator which can be represented by a matrix. But, for example, deducting $-1$ from the other matrices will deduct $-1$ from each entry, which is not supposed to happen. In some of these terms we have to multiply by the unit-matrix to get the matrix, but I do not know where I am supposed to multiply by the unit matrix.

Comment: Would you please state the exact source of this expression? You mentioned below that it's from a research paper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression
$$H=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left[S_{x}^{4}+S_{y}^{4}+S_{z}^{4}-\frac{1}{5} S(S+1)\left(3 S^{2}+3 S-1\right)\right]$$
is magnificently ambiguous.

The $S_i$s are operators, *but* the expression $S(S+1)$ immediately telegraphs to all physicists that it represents the eigenvalue of the Casimir operator acting on an irrep, $$\hat S ^2= S(S+1)  1\!\!1  .$$

In that case, your first three terms involve operators, and your last term takes *S* to be c-numbers, so it is implied to involve an identity matrix,
$$H= 
=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left[\hat S_{x}^{4}+\hat S_{y}^{4}+\hat S_{z}^{4}-\frac{1}{5} \hat S ^2 (3 \hat S ^2 -1\!\! 1)\right ].
$$
But this is just a guess...

Comment: Thank you for trying. The expression is from a research paper, and sadly they present it like that, without explanations nor 'hats' to denote operators. Now, can I ask you why $S(S+1)$ is sometimes used instead of simply writing $S^2$?

Comment: Oh, because, for an irreducible rep,  $\hat S ^2$ is insufferably pompous! After you clear the conceptual fuzz, you of course represent a multiple of the identity with its multiplicative factor eigenvalue and skip the identity. You may only do this if you are acting on an irreducible representation! Otherwise there are block eigenvalues for the diagonal blocks.

Comment: Aha, well thank you. I think I can make sense of it now.